# Why is Android Studio displaying the path on just one of my tabs?

Tags: android, android-studio

Very simple but very annoying question...

In Android Studio, one of my tabs is showing the full path and none of the others are. Whenever I open this particular file it always shows the path.

See the screenshot below, the file "my_events_list_item.xml" is the only one that has the path preceding it. None of the others have!

[image: Android Studio tabs image]

Whenever I open this particular file it always displays the path along with the filename. I am guessing I have set an inadvertent switch somewhere to make this happen. How do I turn it off so I just have the filename displaying (like all the other tabs !?

A minuscule problem I admit, but an annoyance.

Comment: "Whenever I open this particular file it always displays the path along with the filename" -- are you sure about that? Usually, I only get that full-path behavior when I have two tabs open on files with the same basename (e.g., `my_events_list_item.xml`).

Comment: because there is an ambiguity as you have to files with the same name. Android studio is helping you recognize which file it is.

Comment: I have had a good look but I don't have any duplicate file names. I suspected that Android Studio might THINK I had a 'same file name' so I did a 'invalidate caches/restart'. On restart, the path had gone! (YAY) but as soon as the Gradle Synch completed it reappeared (BOO). I shall search through the files again. And I do have a duplicate in `build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout`, but then I have system generated duplicates for all the files in there so I doubt that's the problem?

Answer (score 4):

If you have **same file name** in *various folders*, it will show like this to avoid confusion. In your case "my_events_list_item.xml" will be in two folders. Different folder can be in same application or library or other application too.

Comment: I have had a good look but I don't have any duplicate file names. I suspected that Android Studio might THINK I had a 'same file name' so I did a 'invalidate caches/restart'. On restart, the path had gone! (YAY) but as soon as the Gradle Synch completed it reappeared (BOO). I shall search through the files again. And I do have a duplicate in `build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\layout`, but then I have system generated duplicates for all the files in there so I doubt that's the problem?

Comment: OK I've renamed the file and the path has disappeared so i deduce that a duplicate must be the problem. I just can't find it anywhere (including doing a full disk search for `my_events_list_item.xml`

Comment: In Android Studio IDE, you are adding libraries as JAR,AAR or repository dependency. When you run Gradle Build, Android Studio will extract all your dependencies(libraries) to make your whole project. So it will make a copy of your files(source-java and resource-xml files) in order to make your application apk(Application Package). So it is not a problem. It is an essential thing to make your application.

Comment: It will reappear when you to try to build your application. It is not problem. It is a need of building/packaging tool(gradle) to make your application. No need to worry about that. Happy coding.

Comment: It's not causing me any problems. I just like things to look neat and I find this particularly annoying :)